# Com object in Java , possible?

Tags: java, com

sorry for stupid question but I don't have any experience with java , nothing about jvm , and it's internals,
googling the subj doesn't gave results.

The question is if it's possible to write a com object with Java ? then run it from C# ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes , you can use COM Object from Java, Try to read this Link : [Using a COM Object from Java](https://notendur.hi.is/snorri/SDK-docs/getstart/javac003.htm)

but i don't know the second part