# Call .dll functions using Java

Tags: java, dll, jna, rundll32

I need to write an application for a client that calls a method from a ".dll" file. The ".dll" file was previously executed manually from an ".exe" GUI but now they want to automate the process.

I never worked with .dll files so everything that I found until now is the result of a complete day of research, I also received a small documentation with this tool:

*The interface is an ActiveX DLL which provides two functions (GetUnitInfo and SaveResult).*

In the moment I just want to run the "GetUnitInfo" method from the Winwdows command line using RUNDLL32.exe.

This is the documentation for the "GetUnitInfo" method:
*The interface for GetUnitInfo is as follows:*

```
Public Function GetUnitInfo( _
ByVal strRequest As String, _
ByRef strUnitInfo As String,
Optional ByVal strStationName As String = "") As Long
```

*Sample calling code can be:*

```
Dim lRet As Long
    Dim strXML as String
    lRet = GetUnitInfo( _“<?xml version=""1.0"" ?><GetUnitInfo 
    xmlns=""urn:GetUnitInfo-schema"" SerialNumber=""BD3ZZTC8MA"" />",  strXML)
```

So I tried to run this method with some dummy parameters because the method returns an error if the parameters are not OK. The command:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE FFTester.dll, GetUnitInfo test1, test2
```

But I receive this error:

[image]

I used "Dependency Walker" to list the functions from the dll file:
[image]

But this are all the functions, normally I would expected that also "GetUnitInfo" is listed.

Can somebody help? It is not mandatory to use RUNDLL32.

Later edit:
I want to call this DLL from a tool that is written in JAVA, I tried to use JNA but I failed so I was thinking to call the dll functions from the command line because if this works I can use a process builder to execute the command.

Comment: This is not a normal DLL, the kind that would have an exported function named GetUnitInfo().  It is a COM library, rundll32.exe is not going to be useful.  You forgot to mention the programming tool you use, but in general you want to add a reference to the type library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added an edit to my question

Comment: I still have no idea why this question is tagged with [c#].  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124699/com-object-in-java-possible) to get somewhere.

Comment: I do not have a complete answer. I think you can import the DLL . Then create an object and that object will have the methods from the dll that you can call direct. I had an example for c# command line but can not find it now. (import as in a line in the code, not importing into your IDE.)

Comment: Hi William, sounds good. But I don't know where you mean to import it

Comment: You may be able to call the `GetUnitInfo` method from Javascript, with the command line `cscript.exe`. You'all have to first use `var theObj=new ActiveXObject("TheProgID");` Do you have the ProgID for the ActiveX? (and beware 32/64 bits issues when launching cscript)

Comment: And, obviously, you may be able to use VBScript in the same way, if you're more comfortable with that langage.

Comment: [You can even use Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623773/how-to-use-powershell-to-access-methods-and-properties-of-a-third-party-ole-dll) and use .NET's COM library if you're familiar with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem and I will provide a solution, maybe it will help someone else.

I used [com4j](https://github.com/kohsuke/com4j/blob/master/src/site/markdown/tutorial.md) library to generate the interfaces for my dll. After this you need to register your DLL otherwise most problely your code will throw an "ComException", you can read more [in my second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423026/failed-to-execute-com-class-com4j-comexception-80040154-cocreateinstance-faile).
To register a DLL:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32.exe "path to your DLL" for 32 bit DLL

Or

C:\Windows\System32>regsvr32.exe "path to your DLL" for 64 bit DLL

Also depending on your DLL type, 32 or 64 bit, you need to use proper Eclipse/JDK.