# Failed to execute COM class: com4j.ComException: 80040154 CoCreateInstance failed : Class not registered : .\com4j.cpp:153

Tags: java, dll, comm, com4j

I'm trying for some days to execute a ".dll" file from an JAVA application. If you are interested you can read my first question: [Call a .dll function using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392321/call-a-dll-function-using-command-line)

I used "com4j" to create the COM classes for my DLL. The generated classes looks good and I tried to execute the code, more exactly a method called "getUnitInfo" located in a class called "_Tester":

```
@DISPID(1610809376) //= 0x60030020. The runtime will prefer the VTID if present
  @VTID(8)
  int getUnitInfo(
    java.lang.String strRequest,
    Holder<java.lang.String> strUnitInfo,
    @Optional @DefaultValue("") java.lang.String strStationName,
    @Optional @DefaultValue("") java.lang.String strUserID);
```

The instance:

```
Holder<String> holder = new Holder<String>("test");
        _Tester instance =  ClassFactory.createTester();
        instance.getUnitInfo("", holder, "", "");
```

But it throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com4j.ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 80040154 CoCreateInstance failed : Class not registered : .\com4j.cpp:153
    at com4j.ComThread.execute(ComThread.java:203)
    at com4j.Task.execute(Task.java:25)
    at com4j.COM4J.createInstance(COM4J.java:97)
    at com4j.COM4J.createInstance(COM4J.java:72)
    at DLL.ClassFactory.createTester(ClassFactory.java:21)
    at proiect.DllTest.run(DllTest.java:17)
    at proiect.DllTest.main(DllTest.java:11)
```

I have read a lot of posts regarding this problem on the internet but nothing helped.
Using "PE deconstruct" tool to find out that the .dll file that I need to execute is 32 bit based. I have a 64 bit Windows OS but I installed a 32 bit JAVA and Eclipse.

If I execute "java -version" o the command line:

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

The com4j documentation is lacking information, I think the new generated JAva code still need to communicate with the old DLL but I don't know how it has to be referenced.

Can anybody help?

**EDIT**
The instance is create using this UUID:

```
 public static DLL._Tester createTester() {
    return COM4J.createInstance( DLL._Tester.class, "{4B7CF2DB-F936-4BA3-9DC6-5E99E5220270}" );
  }
```

And I found this in the Windows registry:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoCreateInstance failed : Class not registered` means the GUID you provided does not match any COM item in your Windows registry.

You can try loading a COM object with a different GUID- go into system registry and find any valid GUID, maybe the one associated with Microsoft Excel (in my case, the entry is located under `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Application\CLSID`).

To register your DLL, maybe [How do I register a DLL file on Windows 7 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit) helps.

**EDIT**
Check your registry under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID`.
Is you GUID listed under Classes?

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I checked the registry. Please review the "edit" section of my question.

Comment: Thanks!!! You put me on the right track to fix this. I had to register the .dll. It help Liam's response from your link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13396451/3018671

Comment: Happy to hear that. Out of curiosity, how are you then able to invoke the two methods from com4j? You need to identify each method (using VTID I think), but how do you retrieve this number?

Comment: I used com4j library that generated the interfaces for me:  @DISPID(1610809392) //= 0x60030030. The runtime will prefer the VTID if present
  @VTID(16)
  int saveResult(
    @MarshalAs(NativeType.VARIANT) java.lang.Object strXMLResultText);   I will post an answer in my first question.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have faced the same issue one month back and the final resolution i have founded which has resolved my issue is changing my java 64bit to 32 bit, and it started working. 
note- only add com4j.jar in build path and do not register any .dll files.

Hope this will work for you